# Azure manage App Registration secrets API using a Service Principal user

Tags: azure, service-principal

## Context

I'm implementing a service to rotate the secrets of the service principals. The authenticated user must be a Service Principal and it can only update the secrets from specifics service principals of my organization.

Ex.:

- **Service Principal**: aadapp-manage -> this is the authenticated service principal
- **Service Principal**: aadapp-user-01 -> this is a specifc SP that aadapp-manage can manage its secrets
- **Service Principal**: aadapp-user-02 -> this is a specifc SP that aadapp-manage can manage its secrets
- **Service Principal**: aadapp-user-03 -> this SP **CANNOT** be have its secrets modified by the aadapp-manage SP.

## What I did

- Created an AD Role named `Got-ManagedSecrets-Role` and assign the *microsoft.directory/servicePrincipals/synchronizationCredentials/manage* permission.
  Then, within the PIM, I assigned
- Created an AD Group named `aadgrp-managed-secrets` and added the SPs `aadapp-user-01` and `aadapp-user-02`.
- Underneath PIM, created an assignment with the following entries:

  - **Role**: Got-ManagedSecrets-Role
  - **Scope**: Group
  - **Selected Scope**: aadapp-manage
  - **Selected Application**: aadgrp-managed-secrets

I granted `Delegated / Application.ReadWrite.All`, one of the required permission described in the MS Docs, but this is not useful when I want to restrict the SP that my authenticated user can do.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

[image]

## Test Cases

### HTTP Request 01

Validate if `aadapp-managed-secrets` SP can generate a secret for `aadapp-user-01`. **Expeccted result**: YES

```
POST /v1.0/applications(appId='[USER-01-ID]')/addPassword HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]
Content-Length: 96

{
  "passwordCredential": {
    "displayName": "New Secret"
  }
}
```

**Response**

**Status**: OK (new secret generated)

### HTTP Request 02

Validate if `aadapp-managed-secrets` SP can generate a secret for `aadapp-user-02`. **Expeccted result**: YES

```
POST /v1.0/applications(appId='[USER-02-ID]')/addPassword HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]
Content-Length: 96

{
  "passwordCredential": {
    "displayName": "New Secret"
  }
}
```

**Response**

**Status**: OK (new secret generated)

### HTTP Request 03

Validate if `aadapp-managed-secrets` SP **CANNOT** generate a secret for `aadapp-user-03`. **Expeccted result**: NO

```
POST /v1.0/applications(appId='[USER-03-ID]')/addPassword HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]
Content-Length: 96

{
  "passwordCredential": {
    "displayName": "New Secret"
  }
}
```

**Response**

**Status**: OK (new secret generated). At this point, my test failed.

## Problem

Given that (at least what I thought) I setup the Role and the assignment, it seems that the Graph API step through those securities concerns.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that, `microsoft.directory/servicePrincipals/credentials/update`, `microsoft.directory/applications/credentials/update` and
> `microsoft.directory/servicePrincipals/synchronizationCredentials/manage`
> permissions are required to create secrets for Service principal.

I created four Azure AD Applications like below:

[image]

And created a group `aadgrp-managed-secrets` and added Service Principals as members:

[image]

Now, created a **custom role** and assigned to the group as scope and `aadgrp-managed-secrets` as member:

[image]

[image]

I generated access token for `aadapp-manage` like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When I tried to create secret for `aadapp-user-03`, it got created, but it shouldn't be the case:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{id}/addPassword
Content-type: application/json

{
  "passwordCredential": {
    "displayName": "Password friendly name"
  }
}
```

[image]

Note that: As you granted Admin consent to the API permission `Application.ReadWrite.All` of the Application `aadapp-manage`, it is not possible to restrict the application to stop creating the secrets for `aadapp-user-03`. The Application can create secrets for all the applications in the tenant. The Graph API permission is allowing the Application to create secrets through those security concerns.

**Reference:**

[Custom role permissions for app registration - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-available-permissions#microsoftdirectoryapplicationscredentialsupdate)